# Swift сохранение данных при переходе в неактивное состояние

Tags: swift

Вопрос такой 
у меня есть Scene delegate и у него есть метод sceneWillResignActive, который срабатывает, когда приложение переходит в неактивное состояние
Как мне сохранить массив данных из Vc, когда я перехожу в неактивное состояние

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете подписаться во вью контроллере на уведомление `willResignActiveNotification` и сохранять данные там.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(sceneWillResignActiveNotification(_:)),
                                               name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification,
                                               object: nil)
    }

    @objc func sceneWillResignActiveNotification(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        print(notification)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let array = ["Hello", "World"]
defaults.set(array, forKey: "SavedArray")

let savedArray = defaults.object(forKey: "SavedArray") as? [String]
```

Можно так сохранить,
уходишь в неактивное, сохраняешь,
вернулся, проверил, есть, юзаешь